# laravel passport oauth: Client error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I've replicated Taylor Otwell's frontend / backend passport example from Laracast, on a local host windows: backend running 127.0.0.1:8000 and frontend running 127.0.0.:8080 
When I attempt a client api call - **127.0.0.1:8080/callback** I get this:

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
Client error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token` 
resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":"invalid_request","message":"The request is missing a required
 parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, (truncated...)
```

and this detail:

```
at Client request('post','http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token',
array('form_params' => array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
'client_id' => 3, 
'client_secret' =>'23GCROVkVMtQqKsJKmx2xPojiDU4TOOe3ZMvKvQh', 
'redirect_uri' =>'http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback', 'code' => null),
 'synchronous' =>true)) in Client.php line 87 

at Client->__call('post', array('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token',
 array('form_params' =>array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
'client_id' => 3, 
'client_secret' =>'23GCROVkVMtQqKsJKmx2xPojiDU4TOOe3ZMvKvQh',
'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback', 'code' => null))))in web.php line 3
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
Route::get('/callback', function () {

    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 3,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => ''
    ]);

    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});

Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token',[
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => 3,
        'client_secret' => '23GCROVkVMtQqKsJKmx2xPojiDU4TOOe3ZMvKvQh',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback',
        'code' => $request -> code,
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(),true);
```

Appreciate any suggestions

*(fyi, I have HasApiTokens set up in User Model as well as all other requirements.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with attempting to run both laravel client and laravel back end on local host)*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the post hit after the oauth/authorize redirect has some params missing. It is usually because the code must have expired. I would recommend to do the whole login - authorize cycle again.

Comment: I must say, I was skeptical about this comment, but you're right. You could spend too much time trying to understand what's wrong, hit F5 multiple times when truth is, nothing's going to change. Token has expired :)